# Ruby on Rails: URL parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-parameters

I have a view

> ```
> #myView.html.erb
> <% @data = MyModel.where(mymodel_id: '1').take %>
> <%= link_to 'myController', myController_path(:myView_data => @data)%>
> ```

MyModel.rb contains ***column id*** and ***column name***

and in my controller I have

> ```
> #MyController.rb
> flag = params[:myView_data] #flag now is equal to the id of @data
> ```

and this all works fine, but my problem is flag now has the ***id of params[:myView_data]***, and what I really want is that flag will have the ***name not the id***

here is a sample of what I want to happen

> ```
> #MyController.rb
> flag = params[:myView_data].name #flag must contain the name not the id
> ```

if somehow this is possible, please help :) thanks

Comment: Can you post the `output` when you `inspect` your `params[:myView_data]`?

Comment: What is the use of the `flag` if you are not using it in the `view`?

Comment: if I display params[:myView_data] it only displays the id

Comment: I will only use flag inside the controller not in any view. I will use it for my query inside myController

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a record to the **link_to** method like you did, Rails will by default convert this param to an **id** getting `@model.id`. So what's happening is that the value you're getting in `params[:myView_data]` has the **id** in it. Always. You need to do:

```
<%= link_to 'myController', myController_path(:myView_data => @data.name)%>
```

If you want to change this default behaviour, you can do it in your class. Just override [to_param](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) in your model. Like:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param  # overridden
    data #a string
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @Tiago Farias , thank you for giving me the idea about the value of  params[:myView_data]. But I already did that. if I use this the url will display the name, and I don't want that to happen. is there any other way?

Comment: If you do what? Suggestion 1 or 2?

Comment: Another thing is. It's a HTTP GET method being used in link_to by default. So the URL query WILL be displayed. You can avoid that using the :method parameter in it. But of course, you'll need to alter your route according to it.

Comment: I already did both of your suggestion. I still want to view the url but using the id(www.mywebsite/12) not the name(www.mywebsite/Einstein)

Comment: So you want the id in the url and receive name as a param in your controller also?

Comment: yes sir. that's exactly what I want, is that even possible?

Comment: I'm sorry. You cannot pass both choosing which one to display.

Comment: You can pass both if you want. Like: myController_path(:myView_data => @data.id, :other => @data.name). This way both will be displayed in the url.

Answer (score 1):

**System**

To further `Tiago Farias`'s answer, you need to consider the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which Rails is built around:

[image]

**MVC** is strange at the beginning, because it seems somewhat illogical. You'd imagine it starts with the "view", but you're wrong; it starts with the "controller" -- which is called per request.

Rails is a [stateless framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) (built on HTTP), meaning that every request you send is considered individual / unique (whereas a native application will treat each request as part of a persistent flow). This means that everything you do (the "logic" of your application's interactivity needs to reside in the controller; which will pass fully assembled `Model` objects to your `view`

A common issue for many Rails developers (who are attracted to the framework because of its low barrier to entry) is that they either don't understand, or are confused with, the MVC process; leading them to include direct `Model` calls in the `views` of their application

---

**Views**

The reason I explain this is because you need to appreciate the [**object orientated**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) nature of Rails. More specifically, how you need to **build your objects in your controller**, pass them to your `views`, and consequently manipulate them in your `Model`

As a rule, you should ONLY pass objects to your views. Your views should ONLY pass a single "reference" to your controller (allowing it to build the correct objects for you), leaving your controller to converse with your model:

```
#app/controllers/my_controller.rb
Class MyController < ApplicationController
   def my_view
     @data = MyModel.find 1
   end
end

#app/views/controller/my_view.html.erb
<%= link_to 'myController', myController_path(@data)%>
```

---

## Fix

You need to consider something *very* important - that you're creating an *application*, not a website. As such, you need to use "object orientated programming" to ensure you're able to create the most efficient & succinct code possible.

```
1. Appreciate the Rails Routing Structure
2. Appreciate the object-orientated backend
3. Appreciate how to build / deliver data to the frontend of your application
```

**[Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)**

Your routing is messed up if you have to pass a specific parameter (`myView_data`) to your controller. That's Microsoft-level complexity right there

[image]

As per the object (resource) orientated structure of Rails, you the Routes work in the same way. Using the `resources` directive in the routes builds a series of CRUD methods around the object you want:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :my_controller #-> domain.com/my_controller/:id
```

This means you can then reference the following:

```
<%= link_to "Controller", my_controller_path(@object) %> #-> domain.com/my_controller/2
```

-

**OOP Backend**

When you send data to your controller / model backend, you need to appreciate something very important - it will work as object-orientated. This means that it *expects* you to send the identifying [primary_key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) to help Rails identify the object you're working with.

You simply shouldn't use the `myView_data` param - it's too verbose & complex. Rails' leaning towards [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) means that you should really focus on passing the `id`, or a unique [slug](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#friendlyid) to your backend:

```
#app/controllers/my_controller.rb
Class MyController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @model = Model.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

-

**Frontend**

Finally, you need to consider your frontend

You're passing a specific parameter to your backend, meaning you have to had that in your frontend already. You need to construct your frontend *around* objects - allowing you to `create, read, update, destroy` them

You need to construct your views *around* these objects in your application in order to make it work correctly

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am wondering, will

```
    MyModel.where(mymodel_id: '1').take
```

return an id.

Better use

```
    @data = MyModel.where(mymodel_id: '1').last.id
```

because where will return an array of objects not single object

Then You can do it in two ways:

first way, 
       using that id which is stored in params[:myView_data], you can find whole object

```
   name = MyModel.find(:id => params[:myView_data]).name
```

second way,
        you could directly find name in the view itself

```
   @data = MyModel.where(mymodel_id: '1').last.name
```

Comment: `where` doesn't return an Array but an [`ActiveRecort::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) object (which behaves a lot like an Array. `take` will return the first element of that relation (i.e. it performs a `SELECT ... LIMIT 1` and builds the model). See [AR finder methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-take).

Comment: hi I'm sorry I'm new to rails. May I know the value of params[:myView_data]? Does it have the both the id and the name in it? or just the id?

Comment: @TripleAMAC it will be having an object contains both the fileds id,name.